# Does the dual of a line bundle with no sections have a section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

Let $L \to X$ be a holomorphic line bundle over a compact complex manifold. Suppose $L$  is non-trivial and has no non-trivial sections. Let me ask the following (hopefully not entirely trivial) question:

> Does the dual $L^{\ast}$ have a non-trivial section?

A special case of this is when $L$ is the dual of an ample line bundle. Obviously ample line bundles have sections, but the dual does not.

Comment: Even simpler, take $L=[P-Q]$ on a non-rational curve.

Comment: The linked duplicate gives an example of a pair of line bundles $L,L^*$ on an algebraic curve (i.e. Riemann surface) where neither has a nontrivial section. In fact, this shows that your assertion that ample line bundles have sections is false: any line bundle of positive degree on a curve is ample, but this one has no sections.